# Possible Jules Verne novel where the hero's uncle becomes his brother-in-law

Tags: story-identification, novel, jules-verne

Based on some comments here and [discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/53718901#53718901) it appears that **I may be mistaken in my identification of this as being a Verne novel**. If not, it would have been reasonably contemporaneous; travel by steamship and a general Victorian era setting. It is conceivable that I may have picked other works in a similar vein based on my enjoyment of Verne, subject to their being available in the YA SF section of a public library in the late 1970s. (Being Victorian in sensibility they would have been considered fairly YA-friendly, not having any sex and minimal graphic violence and grotesquerie.)

In the late 1970s I read a bunch of [Jules Verne novels](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/ea.cgi?159) (in English translation) at my local library. Some browsing on ISFDb finds that an [entire series of translations](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pubseries.cgi?271) was published in the 1960s. (At least some of the works I read did *not* come from this series, since I read [*L'île mystérieuse*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?7397) as [*The Mysterious Island*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?2487779) not [*Dropped from the Clouds*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?2660927).) The covers of all of them were dull-coloured library re-binds, so no help there.

I have been able to find some of the stories on [Project Gutenberg](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/58835/58835-h/58835-h.htm), albeit sometimes under alternate names. (I read [*Sans dessus dessous*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?7377) as *The Purchase of the North Pole*, not *Topsy-Turvy* as on PG.) Other stories are not on PG in English *or* French (e.g. [*L'Étoile du Sud*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?7409) which only has a Dutch translation posted), but I've been able to recognize them from descriptions elsewhere.

Nevertheless, there is still at least one story I haven't been able to recognize. Unfortunately, it is more of a geographical marvel/travel adventure crossed with a Victorian romance (but aren't most of them?) than something with a distinctive element like a [Lost World](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/LostWorld) or a [cryptid](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/OurCryptidsAreMoreMysterious) story. As best as I can recall the destination the protagonist took ship for was mountainous but not polar; possibly the Andes or the Himalayas. There might have been a volcano, but that was pretty common in stories of the type, and I may be conflating it with another story.

The one distinctive element I clearly recall is that the protagonist was travelling with his *uncle* who, very unlike [*Voyage au centre de la terre*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?7388), was extremely close in age and temperament. His uncle was only a few, around 3-5, years older, and people commonly mistook them for brothers. (I vaguely recollect a scene where they had a bit of fun with this.)

The pair of them end up in the company of two sisters, who I recall as being somewhat more hardy than the typical women of the era/genre. (Not that they would be considered athletic, but at least they didn't tend to faint all the time, and didn't need to be carried about in litters. And unlike in *Voyage...* and others at least they were along for the adventure instead of back home.) Of course at the end of the story they marry the sisters, and the protagonist remarks on the fact that his uncle is now also his brother-in-law.

This having come up with naught so far, **I will consider possible answers that relax the uncle-nephew relationship to any other familial relationship**, though I'm positive that the men were definitely related.

The climactic scene involved the group trying to escape some imminent danger, following a rugged, rocky trail uphill (it may have been along a crevasse or through a tunnel) to escape from some peril. It may have been as threatening as a rising tide of floodwater or lava or it might just have been a necessity to flee certain hypothermia or heat prostration, but the men had to help the women struggle along and ultimately they all made it.

I was recently reminded of this story by reading [*Beyond the Great South Wall: The Secret of the Antarctic*](https://archive.org/details/beyondgreatsouth00savi/page/n10/mode/2up) by Frank Savile which had a similar "companions marry sisters" ending. (But which was not the book, since this one involved a dinosaur I would certainly have distinctly remembered.)

Comment: I have the [Delphi Complete works e-book](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Delphi-Complete-Works-Jules-Illustrated-ebook/dp/B006IGU7J4), which being an ebook is searchable. I've searched it for various permutations of "brother-in-law" but can't find anything matching the remark you remember.

Comment: Wikisource has the original text of a lot of Jules Verne books: https://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/Auteur:Jules_Verne .  It also has some older translations to other languages.

Comment: the closest I can find is "The Golden Volcano" but that's two male cousins accompanied by two sisters....the 'sisters' are nuns. Probably not marriage material

Comment: I find myself wondering just how sure you are that this one was definitely written by Jules Verne -- as opposed to being "a similar type of adventure novel, written by one of his contemporaries, back around the late 19th or early 20th Century," which you might have stumbled across at the same time you were on that Verne kick in the late 1970s.

Comment: @Lorendiac I was planning on amending the question, especially based on JohnRennie's comment, but haven't had time yet today.  I'm definitely willing to consider that I've got that part wrong.